# want to edit the textView in listView

Tags: android, list, listview, adapter, android-tablelayout

one table row(with 4 TextView) is in one layout and listView in another layout..Want to edit the one of the textView in the list..

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { "Barcode", "Division", "Mrp","qty" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.txt, R.id.txt1, R.id.mrp,R.id.qty1 });

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

> Want to edit qty in the list everytime the row binding...

Answer (score 0):

Then don't pass it a new String array.  Store the String array you pass it in a variable.  When you want to update it, change the appropriate string in the array then call notifyDataSetUpdate() on the adapter to make it reload its data.

Comment: hi thx for the reply..i'am new to android..so did u have any sample about ur idea u given...

Answer (score 0):

```
         ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { "Barcode", "Division", "Mrp","**quantity**" }, new int[] {
                R.id.txt, R.id.txt1, R.id.mrp,R.id.qty1 });

          setListAdapter(adapter);
```